# Pagination in recycler list view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

How to implement pagination in recycler listview. I have to show 10 items per page. Can any one tell me how to deal with this?

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate

Comment: If you don't want to use any library, you can set onscrolllistener for the recyclerview and keep on adding items to the adapter and notifydataset change.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scroll listener on recycler view and call the next paginated api on following condition:

```
 recyclerList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
          int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
          int totalItemCount =  mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
          int pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager
              .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
          int currentPos = pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount;
            if (currentPos >= totalItemCount) {
              callNextApi();
            }
          }
        }
      });
```